# Reading freely available UVR data using gfortran on mac OSX

Tags: macos, perl, fortran

I would like to use fortran to read ultraviolet radiation data that has been produced by the Japan Aerospace Exploration Agency. This data is at a daily and monthly temporal resolution from 2000-2010 at a ~5 km spatial resolution. This question is worth answering as the data could be useful for a number of environment/health projects and is freely available, with proper acknowledgement of source and sharing of preprint of any subsequent publications, from:

ftp://suzaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/pub/GLI/glical/Global_05km/monthly/uvb/

There is a readme file available, which provides instructions on how to read data using fortran as follows:

**Instructions for _le files**

*Header*

```
Read header (size= pixel size *2byte):
character head*14400

read(10,rec=1) head
read(head,'(2i6,2f8.2,f8.4,2e12.5,a1,a8,a1,a40)') 
     & npixel,nline,lon_min,lat_max,reso,slope,offset,',',
     & para,',',outfile
```

*Read data (e.g., fortran77)*

```
parameter(nl=7200, ml=3601)

... open file by "unformatted", "recl=nl*2(byte)" (,"bytereclen")

integer*2 i2buf(nl,ml)
do m=1,ml
 read(10,rec=1+m) (i2buf(n,m), n=1,nl)
 do n=1,nl
   par=i2buf(n,m)*slope+offset
   write(6,*) 'PAR[Ein/m^2/day]=',par
 enddo
enddo
```

*slope values*

par__le : daily PAR [Ein/m^2/day] = DN * 0.01

dpar_le : direct PAR = DN * 0.01

swr__le : daily mean shortwave radiation [W/m^2] = DN * 0.01

tip__le : transmittance of instantaneous PAR at noon = DN * 0.0001

uva__le : daily mean UVA [W/m^2] = DN * 0.001

uvb__le : daily mean UVB [W/m^2] = DN * 0.0001

rpar_le : PAR-range surface reflectance (TOP of canopy/solid surfaces) = DN * 0.0001 (monthly data only)

*error values*

-1 as signed short integer (int16)

65535 as unsigned short integer (uint16)

**Progress so far**

I have downloaded and installed gfortran successfully on mac OSX. I have downloaded a test file (MOD02SSH_A20000224Av6_v601_7200_3601_uvb__le.gz) and decompressed it. I have created a program file:

```
PROGRAM readuvr
IMPLICIT NONE

!some code

END PROGRAM
```

I will then type the following into the command line to create an executable and run it to extract the data.

```
gfortran -o executable

./executable
```

As a complete beginner to fortran, my question is: how can I use the instructions provided to build a program that can read the data and output it into a text file?

Comment: How about a link to the README file?

Comment: ftp://suzaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/pub/GLI/glical/Global_05km/monthly/readme_Global05km.txt

Comment: as to the simple question at the end you have not told `gfortran` the source..  `gfortran source.f -o executable` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that file expands to 51,868,800 bytes. The comments imply the header is 14,400 bytes, which leaves 51,854,400 bytes of actual data payload.

There seem to be 7200 lines of data, so that means there are 7202 bytes per line. There seem to be 2 bytes (16-bit samples) so if we assume 2 bytes/sample, that means there are 3601 samples per line, which matches the `ml=3601`.

So basically, you need to read 14,400 bytes of header, then 7200 lines of data, each line consisting of 3601 values, each of those being 2 bytes wide...

Actually, if you are that unfamiliar with FORTRAN, you may like to extract the data with Perl which is already installed and available on OS X anyway. I have started a VERY SIMPLISTIC Perl program that reads the dat and prints the first 2 values on each line:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

# Read 14,400 bytes of header
my $buffer;
my $nBytes = 14400; 
my $bytesRead = read (STDIN, $buffer, $nBytes) ;
my ($npixel,$nline,$lon_min,$lat_max,$reso,$slope,$offset,$junk)=split(' ',$buffer);
print "npixel:$npixel\n";
print "nline:$nline\n";
print "lon_min:$lon_min\n";
print "lat_max:$lat_max\n";
print "reso:$reso\n";
print "slope:$slope\n";
$offset =~ s/,.*//; # strip trailing comma and junk
print "offset:$offset\n";

# Read actual lines of data
my $line;
for(my $m=1;$m<=$nline;$m++){
   read(STDIN,$line,$npixel*2);
   my $x=$npixel*2;
   my @values=unpack("S$x",$line);
   printf "Line: %d",$m;
   for(my $j=0;$j<2;$j++){
      printf ",%f",$values[$j]*$slope+$offset;
   }
   printf "\n"; # newline
}
```

Save it as `go.pl` and then in the Terminal, type the following once to make it executable

```
chmod +x go.pl
```

and then run it like this

```
./go.pl < MOD02SSH_A20000224Av6_v601_7200_3601_uvb__le
```

Sample output extract:

```
npixel:7200
nline:3601
lon_min:0.00
lat_max:90.00
reso:0.0500
slope:0.10000E-03
offset:0.00000E+00
...
...
Line: 3306,0.099800,0.099800
Line: 3307,0.099900,0.099900
Line: 3308,0.099400,0.074200
Line: 3309,0.098900,0.098900
Line: 3310,0.098400,0.098400
Line: 3311,0.074300,0.074200
Line: 3312,0.071300,0.071200
```

Comment: Many thanks Mark, that's been really very helpful. I'm going to have a go at modifying the code to get the data into a file and then onto appending more of the data to that file. Will post the resulting script. Cheers

Comment: Excellent! If you want the output in a file just do `./go.pl < inputfile > outputfile`

Answer (score 0):

fortran (f2003 or so) solution.  (The linked instructions are awful by the way )

```
      implicit none
      character*80 para,outfile
      character(len=:),allocatable::header,infile      
      integer npixel,nline,blen,i
c note kind=2 is not standard. This needs to be a 2-byte integer.
      integer(kind=2),allocatable :: data(:,:)
      real lon_min,lat_max,reso,slope,off
c header is plain text, so first open formatted and
c directly read header data
      infile='MOD02SSH_A20000224Av6_v601_7200_3601_uvb__le'
      open(10,file=infile)
      read(10,*)npixel,nline,lon_min,lat_max,reso,slope,off,
     $     para,outfile
      close(10)
      write(*,*)npixel,nline,lon_min,lat_max,reso,slope,off,
     $     trim(para),' ',trim(outfile)
      blen=2*npixel
      allocate(character(len=blen)::header)
      allocate(data(npixel,nline))
      if( sizeof(data(1,1)).ne.2 )then
         write(*,*)'error kind=2 did not give a 2 byte integer'
         stop
      endif
c now close and reopen for binary read.
c direct access approach:
      open(20,file=infile,access='direct',recl=blen/4)      
c note the granularity of the recl= specifier is not standard.
c ifort uses 4 bytes.  (note this will break if npixel is not even )
      read(20,rec=1)header
      write(*,*)trim(header)
      do i=1,nline
         read(20,rec=i+1)data(:,i)
      enddo
c note streams if available is simpler: (we don't need to know rec len )
c      open(20,file=infile,access='stream')
c      read(20)header,data
      end
```

This is not actually validated because I don't have known file content to compare against.