# How do I use this code in Fortran 77?

Tags: fortran, header-files, raster

This question [Reading freely available UVR data using gfortran on mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29795392/reading-freely-available-uvr-data-using-gfortran-on-mac-osx) is what I was trying to figure out. I am not on a Mac so I don't know how they got it to work. I am using the [g77 compiler](http://www.cs.yorku.ca/~roumani/fortran/ftn.htm).

I don't understand how I have to modify this script to make it work for my file. The script is available [here](ftp://suzaku.eorc.jaxa.jp/pub/GLI/glical/Global_05km/readme_Global05km.txt).

```
    - Read header (size= pixel size *2byte):
character head*14400

read(10,rec=1) head
read(head,'(2i6,2f8.2,f8.4,2e12.5,a1,a8,a1,a40)') 
     & npixel,nline,lon_min,lat_max,reso,slope,offset,',',
     & para,',',outfile

 - Read data (e.g., fortran77)
parameter(nl=7200, ml=3601)
... open file by "unformatted", "recl=nl*2(byte)" (,"bytereclen")

integer*2 i2buf(nl,ml)
do m=1,ml
 read(10,rec=1+m) (i2buf(n,m), n=1,nl)
 do n=1,nl
   par=i2buf(n,m)*slope+offset
   write(6,*) 'PAR[Ein/m^2/day]=',par
 enddo
enddo
```

Comment: Rather than having the links, it is important to have all the relevant information in the question itself (although the link to the other question is fine).  We should be able to answer your question without going to external sources.

Comment: you should also post some sample data, so people can test run your program on the data.

Comment: I suppose I could also add: the fragment you've posted here isn't Fortran 77 (or any Fortran), so please pay attention to what you're providing/copying.

Comment: I can't post sample data because I can't open the files. I guess a sample would just be a grid or matrix of different integers.
I dont understand how it is not fortran? Are do and enddo not fortran commands? Sorry I am just completely lost.

Comment: Pleas DON'T make workarounds around post restrictions. There are good reason why the system did not allow the link without the xxx. All important information (complete code, sample data) should be **inside the question as text**.

Comment: @PaulinaM I posted an answer to the linked question you might find useful I didn't post here because I don't want to try to write f77 compliant code. Upgrade your compiler already.